# PHP performance Target with Xdebug

Tags: php, performance, xdebug, profiler

I begin to work with Xdebug and WinCacheGrind to understand more about the code I wrote.

I'm currently testing a Shopping Cart Object that uses MySQL to store as a persistent session.

Here are the steps the object does on a typical Add to Cart Action:

1. Construct a Cart Session filled with default values
2. Check for an existing Cart Session In MYSQL with
   $_COOKIE['session_id'] AND $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']. If so, mysql
   row populates the Cart Session  *(12ms)*
3. Set Country Code and State Code in the Cart for furter shipping calculation.
4. Add an item
5. Add item options
6. Get Shipping Options (Regular, Express, NextDay) from MYSQL based on Country Code and State Code *(9.1ms)*
7. Calculate Shipping Cost for each Options Based on Weight items in the Cart
8. Set Discount *(0.1ms)*
9. Set User Prefered Shipping Option ex. regular;
10. Save Cart Session in MYSQL *(93ms)*, using php function serialize for cart content.
11. Display Cart values in the VIEW.

The only call to db are on step 2, 6, 11.

There will be of course extra DB call to get Item Details, Item Options and Discount Code. But for the example, I keep it minimal.

For This PHP Request, XDebug give a result of 
**Cumulative Time : 130ms.**

Is it bad?

And my real question would be, How Fast should a Request should be in "ms"? I heard about YouTube who target 200ms Total but, I'm not Google and don't have this team of ultra super genius laser Intelligent 2055 back from the future engineers...

Thanks for the help.

C.

Comment: I've found KCacheGrind to be *far* superior to WinCacheGrind for analysing an xdebug profiler dump -- download it from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/precompiledbin/

Comment: I download KCacheGrind but the cachegrind.* files are not recognized by the software.

Comment: Change the file name: the file format is recognised, but it expects a different naming convention (I don't know why).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, profiling in XDebug itself adds significant performance overheads to your PHP programs.

For this reason, you should not rely on XDebug to give you an absolute speed figure in milliseconds for your code. (that, and the fact that your performance on a test platform is unlikely to be much of an indicator of performance in the real world with different hardware and different numbers of users)

Instead, you should focus on using the profiler output to show you what parts of your program are taking the most time. These are your bottlenecks -- regardless of how fast the program is actually running, some parts will take more than their fair share of the processor time, and these are the aspects you should be focussing on improving. This is what XDebug's profiler aims to help you with.

As far as analysing XDebug's output, I would *strongly* recommend ditching WinCacheGrind and downloading [KCacheGrind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/precompiledbin/) instead. It is a far superior tool (mainly because WinCacheGrind ceased development quite a long time ago). It has some excellent visualisation tools for seeing at a glance just how much of an impact certain bits of your code are having to the system overall.

If you really need to know your absolute performance figures, you could consider switching from XDebug to XHProf. XHProf is a lightweight profiler tool for PHP written by Facebook. It is not as full-featured as XDebug (nor as well established; it's only recently that it's started being noticed), but it is much lighter, and doesn't have as much of an impact on performance while it's in use. I would still recommend XDebug, as it is a lot more capable, but both tools definitely have their place.

You can find out more about XHProf here: http://blog.cnizz.com/2012/05/05/enhanced-php-performance-profiling-with-xhprof/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will check XHProf for sure.
About the performance, do you have any idea in MS should i target?

Comment: As I said, relying on an absolute ms time isn't necessarily a reliable indicator. However, if you've got a 130ms total, with one function taking 90ms of that, then it should be fairly clear where you need to be looking to improve performance.